# Unexpected return type with futures TryStream and SNAFU context

Tags: rust, stream, inotify

I am trying to wrap a stream of INotify `Event`s, and I am not very successful:

```
pub fn doc_stream(
    &mut self,
) -> Result<impl TryStream<Item = Event<std::ffi::OsString>, Error = Error> + '_, Error> {
    Inotify::init()
        .and_then(|mut inotify| {
            inotify
                .add_watch(
                    self.path.clone(),
                    WatchMask::MODIFY | WatchMask::CREATE | WatchMask::DELETE,
                )
                .map(|_| inotify)
        })
        .context(INotifyError)
        .and_then(move |mut inotify| {
            inotify
                .event_stream(&mut self.buffer[..])
                .context(INotifyError)
                .map(|ts| ts.context(INotifyError))
        })
}
```

Toward the end of this function, I have the call `inotify.event_stream(...)` which returns something like `Result<EventStream, ioError>`. With the call to `context`, it becomes a `Result<EventStream, Error>`, but an `EventStream` is defined a `Stream<ioResult<Event>>`, which is equivalent (in my optimist mind) to a `TryStream<Event, ioError>`.

After the `context()`, I expect to have `Result<TryStream<Event, ioError>, Error>`. With the call to `.map(|ts| ts.context(INotifyError))`, I now expect to turn this into a `Result<TryStream<Event, Error>, Error>`, but it's not.... I have a layer of `Result` too many: `Result<TryStream<Result<Event, Error>, Error>, Error>`.

I suspect that the change from `Stream<Result<Foo, _>>` does not turn into `TryStream<Foo, _>`, but rather into a `TryStream<Result<Foo, _>, _>`, but I'm not sure...

---

After a bit of investigation, I am narrowing the question to this:

```
inotify.event_stream(...)
```

return verifies

```
impl Stream<Item = Result<Event<std::ffi::OsString>, io::Error>> + '_,
```

but does not verify

```
impl TryStream<Item = Event<std::ffi::OsString>, Error = io::Error> + '_,
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Ok` instead of `Item` in the TryStream will fix the problem. Doh!